# How can I hide a HTML element when a link is selected with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, navigation

I wanted to create a responsive menu using purely HTML and CSS but an issue I've stumbled upon is that my website uses anchor links for the navigation, not external page links. Because they are anchor links, when one is selected the menu overlay is still there.

How can I use Javascript to add the `display: none` style to the menu when a navigation link is selected? This will need to be able to be overridden again if the user reopens the navigation.

Here's the basic HTML for my navigation:

```
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ nav {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can you display the relevant HTML in your question? Depending on the structure of your existing source code you might find some solutions better than others but without seeing it first, it makes things harder to offer you the best solution. Also is it possible for you to assign your anchor tags with a `class` name "assuming they don't already have one" Or are your anchors child elements to something with an `id`?

Comment: @NewToJS I have added the code for reference. In regards to your question about assigning classes to my anchor tags, yes I would be able to do that if required.

Comment: So it looks like your navigation display is based on the hidden checkbox being checked or unchecked right? If so then all you need to do is assign event listeners to your anchor tag to uncheck that checkbox "If the display is driven by it" I don't suppose you have any javascript the should go with this menu? Something is missing because the menu is always displaying so I can't really give you a working example. Maybe if you could create a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Not really 100% sure if this is what you're looking for but I have put the checkbox on display so you can see it being checked/unchecked https://jsfiddle.net/6k6v34Lw/

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you @NewToJS

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it easily is with jquery (if you aren't using jquery i STRONGLY suggest you start), just add id="menuID" to your menu:

```
<a href="url" onclick="$('#menuID').css('display', 'none');">Click me!</a>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question so I would suggest you explain how to link to the library.

Comment: Thank you but my issue with using jQuery is that I don't want to load the library for this minor thing that I want to achieve. That's if it could be done with just Javascript?

Comment: document.getElementById("menuID").style.display = "none"; should work.